# Favicon is not displaying in the address bar for Firefox browser, when some special character are added with the URL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have tried to solve this Favicon problem, but i haven't got a resolution.

When some special characters like (#r$) are added in the URL (`www.test.com/online/example .aspx#r$`), then the favicon is not displayed in the address bar for Firefox. but it is working fine in all other browsers.

My code is look like the following

```
<link id="favIcon" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

and from server side, i have mentioned the favicon path as

```
 favIcon.Href = "../Images/favicon.ico?guid="+System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

need a resoution to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../Images/favicon.ico?guid='+System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()';" />
```